# Selenium webdriver exception - cannot determine loading status - missing or invaid 'entry.level'

Tags: java, selenium

I was using Selenium 3.4.x with Chrome version 63.0.3239.108 with Chromedriver 2.33.

After I upgraded to Selenium 3.8.0, and Chromedriver 2.34, I started to get the following errors.  I am not sure what's causing it.

This is the error I get......

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot determine loading status from unknown error: missing or invalid 'entry.level' (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.108) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 951 milliseconds Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' System info: host: 'ITS154810C1310', ip: '10.1.30.10', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111-1-ojdkbuild' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed), userDataDir=C:\Users\spatel\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir7472_17124}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=63.0.3239.108, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID: 7074866f88acf5e28212c15e3ee646e7 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:671) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:272) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:82) at samp.pageobjects.PWSPagesHelper.clickWithRetryOnXpathKey(PWSPagesHelper.java:136) at samp.registration.SignInPage.navigateToSignInPage(SignInPage.java:150) at samp.registrationTests.SignInStaticContentTests.navigateToSignInPage(SignInStaticContentTests.java:58) at samp.registrationTests.SignInStaticContentTests.si_P00A1(SignInStaticContentTests.java:69) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86) at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643) at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820) at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128) at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129) at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112) at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782) at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632) at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366) at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361) at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319) at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268) at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52) at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86) at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244) at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169) at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064) at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132) at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236) at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)

Comment: You state that you've updated Chrome driver to 2.34 but the error message says that the installed Chrome driver is 2.25

Comment: I have put version 2.34 in the path that the JAVA code looks for.  However, when I run the test, somehow, old version is getting picked.  I am looking into it... :(

Comment: Using DesiredCapabilities was the rootcause - works with System.setProperties() now.